# When the iOS device is connected to the Bluetooth scanner, the Apple Magic Keyboard cannot input normally

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Bluetooth scanner is used in my iPad App. When using the app, the user used the scanner and also Apple Magic Keyboard in my App.

The scanner is equivalent to an external keyboard, and the Apple Magic Keyboard is also an external keyboard.

Besides, I use textView to receive the input content.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView 
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(receivedBarcode:) withObject:textView.text afterDelay:0.25];
}
```

My questions:

1. It is not possible to use the Apple Magic Keyboard normally for input because, whenever the keyboard is clicked, the delegate method of the textView will be executed.
2. How should I know if the input came from the Scanner or if the user entered it using the Apple Magic Keyboard?
3. Can I use a scanner and an Apple Magic Keyboard on my iPad at the same time? Is there any way to avoid the conflict between the two input models?

Comment: You can't know.  As far as the iPad is concerned they are both keyboards.  You may be able to configure the scanner to prefix its scans with some special character and then you can look for this in your delegate method

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe a good idea, but a lot of customers and it's not very friendly to have them all set up their scanners.

Comment: I agree.  Unfortunately keyboard emulating Bluetooth scanners all have this limitation.  You can get a scanner that doesn't emulate a keyboard, but then you need to write code to interact with it using Core Bluetooth.  Or you need to explain to them that they need to ensure the right input field is selected before they scan.  This is a problem on any platform with keyboard-based scanners; Windows, Mac etc